# Prevent a jQuery function to be called everytime the scroll changes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a function that evaluates if a scroll on an element is happening, if it does it will call some extra functionality, based on boundaries. It is working, nonetheless the function is called multiple times because every little scroll change it triggers the functionality over an over again. How can I make to be called 1 time only (if the value is between the boundaries)?

Since the navbar is intended to be used in mobile, to test it you have to use the arrow keys(left and right) to scroll the bar to the sides.

```js
$('#navegacione li').click(function () {
        $('#navegacione li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
      });
      var lastScrollLeft = 0;
      var anchoLi = $('#navegacione').width();
      var anchoTotal = anchoLi * 4;
      console.log(anchoLi);
      console.log(anchoTotal);
      $('#navegacione').scroll(function () {
        var documentScrollLeft = $('#navegacione').scrollLeft();
        if (lastScrollLeft != documentScrollLeft) {
          //console.log('scroll x');
          lastScrollLeft = documentScrollLeft;
          //console.log(lastScrollLeft);

          var miEstado = false;
          var veces = 0;
          if(lastScrollLeft < anchoLi){
            $('#navegacione li').removeClass('active');
            $('#descripcion').addClass('active');
            // $('#carousel').carousel(0); <-- this call is being repeated every change of scroll
            //console.log('condition 1 in');
          }
          if (lastScrollLeft > anchoLi - 50 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 2   ){
            $('#navegacione li').removeClass('active');
            $('#aprender').addClass('active');
            //$('#carousel').carousel(1); <-- this call is being repeated every change of scroll
            //console.log('condition 2 in');
          } else if(lastScrollLeft > anchoLi * 2 - 50 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 3 ){
            $('#navegacione li').removeClass('active');
            $('#trabajar').addClass('active');
            //$('#informacion-programa').carousel(2);
          } else if (lastScrollLeft > anchoLi * 3  -25 && lastScrollLeft < anchoLi * 4){
              $('#navegacione li').removeClass('active');
              $('#metodo').addClass('active');
              //$('#informacion-programa').carousel(3); <-- this call is being repeated every change of scroll
      
          }
        }
      });
```

```css
<style>
    section#segunda-nav{
        background: blue;
    }
    ul#navegacione{
      background: blue;
    }
    #segunda-nav li {
    min-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    }
    #navegacione li.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid cyan;
}
    #navegacione.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none; /*// IE 10+*/
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;/*// Firefox*/}
  #navegacione.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
  #navegacione.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
  #navegacione.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border-width: 0;
  border-bottom: none;
}
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
}
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li>a::after {
  content: "";  
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
  transform: scale(0);
}
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li.active>a::after,
#navegacione.nav-tabs>li:hover>a::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}
#navegacione.tab-nav>li>a::after {
  background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #fff;
}
#navegacione.tab-pane {
  padding: 15px 0;
}
#navegacione.tab-content {
  padding: 20px
}

#navegacione.nav-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none; /*Safari and Chrome*/
}
.card {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: block;
}

#navegacione.nav>li>a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
#navegacione.nav{
    flex-wrap: inherit; 
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="segunda-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <ul id="navegacione" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li id="descripcion" role="presentation" class="active"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="0" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">DESCRIPCIÓN<br> DEL PROGRAMA</a></li>
                    <li id="aprender" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="1" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">QUÉ VAS A APRENDER</a></li>
                    <li id="trabajar" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="2" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">DÓNDE PUEDES TRABAJAR</a></li>
                    <li id="metodo" role="presentation"><a data-target="#informacion-programa" data-slide-to="3" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">NUESTRO MÉTODO DE ENSEÑANZA</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can't change how it's called. You should just check whether the state (inside or outside the range) has changed, and only do something in that case.

Comment: It sounds like you will want to look into throttling and/or debouncing, which is a way to create a function that either can't be called a second time until a cooldown period has elapsed (a throttled function), or a function that is only called after a certain time has elapsed since it was last attempted to be called (a debounced function). Here's a page you might find to be a useful starting point: [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)

Comment: @Barmar my first attempt was to do that but I find my self unable to complete it